# LCD monitor works for a few seconds, then goes black

Tags: hardware-failure, lcd

When I turn the LCD monitor power on, the normal blue Philips monitor startup screen will display for 3 seconds, followed by the normal desktop for 2 seconds, then it'll go black. Over these 5 seconds, a strange electrical humming/buzzing sound will emit from the monitor. As soon as the monitor goes black, that strange humming/buzzing stops. I never noticed this humming/buzzing when the monitor was working properly. The power light at the bottom of the monitor is still on the whole time, indicating that power is still being fed into the monitor. There is no image burn-in into the screen after it goes black - it's just pitch darkness. Turning down the brightness hasn't helped. The length of time the monitor has been staying on has been reducing, and now only the Philips startup screen will show up for 2 seconds followed by pitch black, whereas before I'd at least be able to see my desktop for a few seconds.

I have multiple other monitors that are still functioning as expected, even if I use the same cable & GPU ports as I'm using with the problem monitor. I've tried different cables and different GPUs.

Comment: Before replacing the monitor, try unplugging the video cable from both ends, and plug them back in. I've seen this weird issue about 10 times now in my life. Nothing but doing that fixes it. The cable must be unplugged from both ends at the same time for this to work though. Like electricity must leak out or something...

Answer (score 1):

> I have multiple other monitors that are still functioning as expected,

You tested different cables and GPU.

And the monitor in question is not working with noises and darkness. Backlight (most likely) has failed, or perhaps some other hardware failure.

Replace the monitor.

Most consumer monitors are not worth fixing economically.